# Can I get PropertyInfo of a property without using its name?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class that has a property, and that property has an `attribute`, and within the `get{}` or `set{}` of that property, I want to access that attribute.

Is there any way of doing this without having to reference the name of the property as a `string`?  Does this work?

```
class MyClass
{
    [DefaultValue("This is my default")]
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            string value = this.db.getMyProperty();
            if (value == null)
            {
                var myPropertyInfo = this.GetType().GetProperty("MyProperty");
                var myAttributeInfo = myPropertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute(
                    typeof (DefaultValueAttribute)) as DefaultValueAttribute;
                if (myAttributeInfo != null)
                    value = myAttributeInfo.defaultValue;
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

What causes me concern about this is that passing the name of the property is a violation of DRY, and makes it too easy to accidentally pass the wrong string.

How can I improve this code to remove duplication?

Comment: This seems way more work than just having a backing field with a default parameter set in it and no attributes or reflection at all.

Comment: I've simplified the problem. The viewmodel we populate this from needs to display the current value, and the value that will be used if the user chooses to restore to default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` to get the current reference from method or a property. In your case, use the `Name` property which will return a string `get_MyProperty` and remove the `get_` part with `substring`, Try this:

```
[DefaultValue("This is my default")]
public string MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        string value = this.db.getMyProperty();
        if (value == null)
        {
            // get property name from GetCurrentMethod.
            // use the SubString to remove the "get_" that comes from .net internals
            var propertyName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.Substring(4);

            // keep your method
            var myPropertyInfo = this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            var myAttributeInfo = myPropertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute(
                typeof (DefaultValueAttribute)) as DefaultValueAttribute;
            if (myAttributeInfo != null)
                value = myAttributeInfo.defaultValue;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name is "get_MyProperty", not "MyProperty", but if the pattern is as consistent as it appears, I could just strip off the "get_".

Comment: @JeffDege: The pattern should be consistent I believe. If you want a another way, you can instead iterate all the properties to find the one that references that "Get" method: `var getMethod = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(); var myPropertyInfo = this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(pinfo => pinfo.GetGetMethod() == getMethod).First();` I won't kid you, it's definitely not as efficient. However, you are producing a _constant_ value, so you could/should probably introduce a caching mechanism.

Comment: Try to apply `.Substring(4)` on the Property name to remove this part of string. It comes from internals of .Net and we cannot change.

Comment: The issue with using `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` is that it will crawl the stack frame to find the current method and the JIT isn't able to inline the method for potential optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what version of the Framework you're using, but if it's .NET 4.5 or later you can use `CallerMemberName`. Add the following method to `MyClass`:

```
private PropertyInfo GetProperty([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
{
   var myPropertyInfo = this.GetType().GetProperty(name);
   return myPropertyInfo;
}
```

Then, in `MyProperty` change

`var myPropertyInfo = this.GetType().GetProperty("MyProperty");`

to

`var myPropertyInfo = this.GetProperty();`

At runtime, the value for `name` parameter of `GetProperty` will be provided automatically for you.

Actually, if you're doing this a lot (and it's always the same attribute) you could simplify this even more:

```
private string GetDefaultValueForProperty([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
{
    string defaultValue = null;
    var myPropertyInfo = this.GetType().GetProperty(name);
    var myAttributeInfo = myPropertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<DefaultValueAttribute>();
    if (myAttributeInfo != null)
    {
        defaultValue = (string)myAttributeInfo.Value;
    }

    return defaultValue;
}
```

Then the code in your property looks like this:

```
[DefaultValue("This is my default")]
public string MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        string value = this.db.getMyProperty();
        if (value == null)
        {
            value = GetDefaultValueForProperty();
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extension method like this:

```
public static TValue GetDefaultValue<TParent, TValue>
  (this TParent @this, Expression<Func<TParent, TValue>> e)
{
  var member = (e.Body as MemberExpression).Member;
  var attr = member.GetCustomAttribute(typeof (DefaultValueAttribute)) 
               as DefaultValueAttribute;

  return (TValue)attr.Value;
}
```

And now you only have to do this in your property:

```
return GetDefaultValue(i => i.MyProperty);
```

Nicer and with compile-time checks and it works with refactoring too :)

The extension method is really bare-bone, you want it to be safer, but the idea should be clear.

Comment: This should have further explanations describing what this does and why it does it in the way you have written.